# Laravel + Livewire: How to fix Pagination Elements Get method error

Tags: laravel

Noob here. Help please.

When I search for something in the input box, then clear the input box again. Then I click any of the Pagination Elements: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, I get this error.

**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

Here's the livewire component

search.blade.php

```php
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
             {{--Previous Page Link--}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true">
                    <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button class="page-link" wire:click="previousPage" rel="prev">&lsaquo;</button>
                </li>
            @endif

             {{--Pagination Elements--}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                 {{--"Three Dots" Separator--}}
                @if (is_string($element))
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
                @endif

                 {{--Array Of Links--}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">{{ $page }}</span></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach

             {{--Next Page Link--}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button class="page-link" wire:click="nextPage" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</button>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true">
                    <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </nav>
@endif
```

search-students.blade.php

```php
{{-- CARD BODY --}}
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="example1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div id="example1_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                    <label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" wire:model="searchText">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid"
                       aria-describedby="example1_info">
                    <thead>
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending">First Name</th>
                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Last Name</th>
                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Image</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($students as $student)

                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">{{ $student->FirstName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $student->LastName }}</td>
                            <td><img src="StudentImage/{{ $student->ImageLink }}.jpg" width="120" height="150"></td>

                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            {{ $students->links('livewire.livewire-pagination') }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{{-- card body --}}
```

Comment: do the next and previous page buttons work?

Comment: can you put your component code as well `search`

Comment: @GiovanniS. Yes, they are working.

Comment: @KamleshPaul Ok. I will include the component code.

Comment: I had the same issue. This worked out for me: https://laptrinhx.com/laravel-8-search-with-pagination-using-livewire-1024914969/  
It's a different approach but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was using pagination in the component class, please check out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66778852/7995302

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Livewire will overwrite a custom view you have defined inside a service provider using: Paginator::defaultView().

When using either method, instead of anchor tags in your pagination component, you should use wire:click handlers with the following methods:

nextPage to navigate to the next page
previousPage to navigate to the previous page
gotoPage($page) to navigate to a specific page.

**See below for an example of how the default livewire paginator works.**

```
<div>
    @if ($paginator->hasPages())
        <nav role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination Navigation" class="flex justify-between">
            <span>
                {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                    <span class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5 rounded-md">
                        {!! __('pagination.previous') !!}
                    </span>
                @else
                    <button wire:click="previousPage" wire:loading.attr="disabled" rel="prev" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 rounded-md hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        {!! __('pagination.previous') !!}
                    </button>
                @endif
            </span>

            <span>
                {{-- Next Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                    <button wire:click="nextPage" wire:loading.attr="disabled" rel="next" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 rounded-md hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        {!! __('pagination.next') !!}
                    </button>
                @else
                    <span class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5 rounded-md">
                        {!! __('pagination.next') !!}
                    </span>
                @endif
            </span>
        </nav>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but a copy paste from the website. Can you help finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should use WithPagination in components like that

```
 use WithPagination;
```

and don't forget to load the namespace

```
use Livewire\WithPagination;
```

now you can use links method like

```
 {{$data->links()}}
```

if pagination numbers are hidden use themes in component classes like

```
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```